# Python Create Multiple Folders From A List

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to create folders from a list. I can get it to create the folders but I want it to be be able to check if there are any folders missing and create the missing ones

```
Folders = ['Folder1','Test','Help']
for i in Folders
    os.makedirs(i)
```

This will create the folders but if i re-run it after deleting one it will just give me errors saying the first folder already exists. Is there any way to check and create the missing folders?

Answer (score 3):

No need to check. Just use `exist_ok=True` argument in `makedirs()`

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use and other function from os: `os.path.isdir('folder name')` which returns a bool: `True` if the file exists and `False` if it doesn't.

In your case:

```
Folders = ['Folder1','Test','Help']
for i in Folders:
    if not os.path.isdir(i):
        os.makedirs(i)
```

That is all :)